# What does the variable "tmmx" in the TerraClimate dataset stand for?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm working with TerraClimate and want to display the mean temperature for different decades in relation to the long term trend. I'm just wondering what exactly the variable "tmmx" is.  Is it the accumulated max. Temperature for 1 year?
Because when you research they say the dataset contains montly average values.

And the shown temperatures are around 300 °C. So when you divide it by 12 (Month) the numbers get more reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Based on queries I can see [like here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/IDAHO_EPSCOR_GRIDMET) (and forgive me as I do not use this), it looks like it stands for the maximum temperature. Might be `tm` = temperature and `mx` = maximum.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-08-01', '2018-08-15'));
var maximumTemperature = dataset.select('tmmx');
var maximumTemperatureVis = {
  min: 290.0,
  max: 314.0,
  palette: ['d8d8d8', '4addff', '5affa3', 'f2ff89', 'ff725c'],
};
```

And bear in mind, most scientific temperatures (including climate science) use Kelvin for temperature. And 300K is about 26.5ºC. However, a user below has pointed out that this dataset is in Celsius.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the data set you have linked, Kelvin is correct. But for TerraClimate the numbers are given in degrees. So they give a range from -670 to 576 °C for maximum temperature... That would be very unrealistic in Kelvin.

Comment: Did you eventually found out what the tmmx exactly stands for?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is related to scale, please refer answer posted by Daniel Wiell:

[How can the maximum temperature (tmmx) band in the TerraClimate GEE dataset be interpreted?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374029/how-can-the-maximum-temperature-tmmx-band-in-the-terraclimate-gee-dataset-be-i)