# How can the maximum temperature (tmmx) band in the TerraClimate GEE dataset be interpreted?

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, time-series, climate

This question was already asked here. But there was no correct answer. [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367048/what-does-the-variable-tmmx-in-the-terraclimate-dataset-stand-for)

I'm using the precipitation, maximum temperature (tmmx) and soil moisture in the TerraClimate dataset in GEE. I cannot find out how to interpret the tmmx values. I have looked into the literature [Link](https://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_journals/2018/rmrs_2018_abatzoglou_j001.pdf) [Link](http://www.climatologylab.org/terraclimate.html) [Link](https://www.worldclim.org/data/monthlywth.html), but couldn't find what these numbers exactly mean.

The tmmx is based on the WorldClim dataset and is apparently "average maximum temperature (°C)"
The range is between -670°C and 576°C (globally) [Link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/IDAHO_EPSCOR_TERRACLIMATE).
Gridded TMN and TMX are derived from gridded TMP and DTR according to:
TMX = TMP + DTR/2 [Link](https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/joc.3711) in appendix 3

My ideas are: 1) it is some other unit (Fahrenheit or Kelvin)(but they say it's in °C)
2) it is accumulated (but nowhere on earth the max T adds up to -670)
3) it is accumulated in another way (temporal or spatial) which leads to these numbers

This is how it looks in GEE for central Europe:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [bands table](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/IDAHO_EPSCOR_TERRACLIMATE#bands), you'll see there's a `scale` column. The scale for `tmmx` is `0.1`. That means the actual temperatures vary between about `-670 * 0.1 °C = -67.0 °C` and `576 * 0.1 °C = 57.6 °C`.

Comment: Ok, I see. I did recognize that scale number, but I thought it is some spatial scaling parameter. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Does that mean, the lowest maximum monthly temperature was -67.0°C?  That is a really low maximum temperature. But let's say it was measured at the coldest place on earth in a winter month and as a record low for the whole time period.

Comment: Yes. Cold, but not unreasonably so. Have a look at what values you get in your area of interest, and verify that it seems reasonable.